# How can I remove the class="form-control" that comes by default the FormControl component in React-Bootstrap

Tags: reactjs

FormControl is a component from react-bootstrap and has by default the class form-control. I want to remove this class when this input is inside the FormGroup with class "mygroup".

```
 <FormGroup className="mygroup">
<FormControl>
</FormGroup>
```

Comment: I hope FormControl is a component that you created and you want "form-control" class removed only if its a child of "FormGroup" component and not removed in other scenarios?

Comment: FormControl is a component from react-bootstrap and has by default the class form-control.  I want to remove this class when this input is inside the FormGroup with class "mygroup".

Answer (score 0):

You can set the prop "bsClass" to override the default styles applied by react-bootstrap.
Set it to empty string or to any custom class that you want.

```
       <FormGroup className="mygroup">
      <FormControl
        bsClass=""
        type="text"
        placeholder="Enter text"
      />
    </FormGroup>
```

More details here - https://5c507d49471426000887a6a7--react-bootstrap.netlify.com/components/forms/

Comment: I add 

<FormControl 
   type="text"
   value="" 
   bsClass="myfield" />

and the class "form-control" by default is not removed.  When I inspect on the browser, this code is generated: 

<input bsclass="myfield" type="text" class="form-control" value="">

Comment: Could you share your code so that I can have a look?